# How to use python stripe payment confirmed payment to access a webpage

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I have an app route to a subscription plan and I want to block access to it for customers who havn't confirmed payment with stripe for example I have a $10 dollar plan anyone who paid $10 within 24 hours can access the page

```
@app.route('/plan10', methods=['POST'])
def plan10():

customer = stripe.Customer.create(
    email=request.form['stripeEmail'],   source=request.form['stripeToken'])

charge = stripe.Charge.create(
    customer=customer.id,
    amount=1000,
    currency='usd',
    description='The Product'
)

return redirect(url_for('basicplan'))
```

The idea is to stop access to the page basicplan without paying by typing www.example.com/basicplan using python and flask

For the login we can do

```
@app.route(/plan)
@login_required
def plan():
   return render_template(plan.html)
```

Now I want to stop access for customers who haven't paid using stripe any help is appreciated using python and flask

Answer (score 1):

You could save the charge ID[0] that you get from Stripe in the `plan10` method and store it with your logged-in user class[1]. Then when someone logs in you can check that they have the charge or not(showing that they've paid).

You could also use the Stripe API to check the status of the charge for an additional check:

```
charge = stripe.Charge.retrieve(user.savedChargeId)
if(charge.status == "succeeded"){
  # allow access
}else{
  # deny access
}
```

[0] - https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#charge_object-id

[1] - https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class

[2] - https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#charge_object-status